# How to force disable Gyroscope in A-FRAME

Tags: javascript, aframe

I wonder can we disable the gyro in a mobile device, with minimal code? I tried to disable some of this property https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/look-controls.html but none is for disable gyro. Do I really need to create my own look-controls.js? If that's true what exactly do I need to change to disable the gyroscope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a new [magicWindowTrackingEnabled](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/components/look-controls.md#properties) property in the look-controls component you can use. It's now available in [master builds](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@33264d8761b8d8ec2862407f32ba4a39e111bb67/dist/aframe-master.min.js) and the upcoming A-Frame 1.1.0 version.

Working example using a master build:

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/cliff-light-glasses?path=index.html%3A18%3A55

Comment: thanks, @Diego this is very helping me a lot. And when will the 1.10 version be released and is it okay if I using the master for the production?

Comment: 1.1.0 is coming this or next week. It's ok to use master builds in the meantime